# Can I install visual studio 2012 after visual studio 2015?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, installation, version, sql-server-data-tools

I have Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 with most recent version of SSDT installed on Windows 2016. Now I found that I need to use Visual Studio 2012 to develop an SSRS report. Is it possible to install Visual Studio 2012 on the same machine in my case？ Should I install SSDT again after VS 2012 installation (if it's possible to install VS 2012 in my case)? I know I can just start to install and see if it work. However, I just want to see if anyone has this experience. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can....

Comment: I don't see any issue,except this recommendation..`We recommend that you install Visual Studio versions in the order in which they were released. For example, install Visual Studio 2013 before you install Visual Studio 2015.` from here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Is it possible to install Visual Studio 2012 on the same machine in my case?

Yes, the VS 2015 can work side by side with VS 2012, usually you should install Visual Studio versions in the order in which they were released. But it should be ok for your case, if you encounter an installation failure, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

> > Should I install SSDT again after VS 2012 installation (if it's possible to install VS 2012 in my case)?

You can have a look at [Install SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500335(v=vs.103).aspx) and you can find the following information:

SQL Server Data Tools ships in **the Professional SKU, or higher**, in Visual Studio 2012. When you run the VS 2012 installer, there is an option feature “Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools” as the following and you can check it to install (it is checked by default) and the installation completed successfully on my side.
[image]
If Visual Studio 2012 is not installed, SQL Server Data Tools will install the Visual Studio 2012 Integrated Shell and install SQL Server Data Tools. The Integrated Shell will only contain SSDT, and does not include VS programming languages and the features that support their respective project systems. For the more detail information, you can check this: [SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015)

Answer (score 0):

I have both VS12 and VS15 working aok. Just install as normal. The only issue I've had is accidently opening projects from VS15 in VS12.